# How to check multiple of TextBox value ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**This is my ASP.NET page :**

```
                    <div id="dvtgl1" style="display: none">1. 
                        <asp:TextBox  ID="TxtTglCuti1"   runat="server" MaxLength="1"  style="width: 140px; height: 35px; padding: 12px 10px;  box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid Silver; border-radius: 4px;" ValidationGroup="MKE"></asp:TextBox><br /><br /></div>                            
                    <div id="dvtgl2" style="display: none">2. 
                        <asp:TextBox  ID="TxtTglCuti2"   runat="server" MaxLength="1"  style="width: 140px; height: 35px; padding: 12px 10px;  box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid Silver; border-radius: 4px; " ValidationGroup="MKE"></asp:TextBox><br /><br /></div>
```

**This is my jQuery script :**

```
$(function(){

            $("#<%= TxtTglCuti1.ClientID %>").datepicker({
                //dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                minDate: dateToday,
                beforeShowDay: DisableMonday

            });
            $("#<%= TxtTglCuti2.ClientID %>").datepicker({
               // dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                minDate: dateToday, beforeShowDay: DisableMonday

            });
```

**This is my VB.NET class :**

```
If (TxtTglCuti1.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti2.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti3.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti4.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti5.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti6.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti7.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti8.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti9.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti10.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti11.Text = "") And (TxtTglCuti12.Text = "") Then
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Data tidak boleh kosong')</script>")
```

Instead of building a block of code to check every `TextBox` that contains the date value from `DateTimePicker` and jQuery of all the text boxes.I built it to assign the value to an array like this :

```
    txt_tgl_cuti(0) = TxtTglCuti1.Text
    txt_tgl_cuti(1) = TxtTglCuti2.Text
```

The thing is, it only works for a small record.

How should I check it dynamically ? I have 12 record of text boxes and my goal is to build a function to prevent users to input duplicate date values in the `TextBox`

Comment: Did you do research before asking this question ? There are already multiple examples on how to use `Control` to go through the all Text Boxes on this website and in the Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Well formatted code makes it easier to read. Please take the time to format your code. In this instance it would help to remove the unnecessary leading spaces but keep indenting. Also if you have an opening html tag on its own line, please put the closing tag on its own line with the same indentation as the opening tag. Basically, take the time to make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: If you were using asp.net validation controls you could assign a custom validation control to each textbox. You could then create a client side script and server side function to check for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the simle way you can check all text box values are blank,

**.ASPX**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhDates" runat="server">
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="text" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

**.VB**

```
Protected Function MySub() As Boolean
        For Each ctl As Control In plhDates.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then
                If (CType(ctl, TextBox).Text = "") Then
                    Return True
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return False
End Function

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim isContainBlankValue As Boolean = MySub() //return true if any of the textbox have blank value
End Sub
```

Comment: well thank you to try this case , i will try to implement this block and do some modification to check duplicate data from textbox